# Discord buttons not sent

Tags: button, discord, discord.js

When I run this code, the bot only sends "Hello" and the mbed without buttons and it doesn't give any error. Why is this happening and how can I fix it? I would appreciate any help.

```js
const { MessageButton } = require("discord-buttons")
const embed = this.client.embed()
.setTitle("Are you smart")
.setColor("BLUE")
    
const yes = new MessageButton()
.setStyle("green")
.setLabel( 'Yes')
.setID("smart")
    
const no = new MessageButton()
.setStyle("red")
.setLabel("No")
.setID("dumbass")
  msg.send("Hello", {
buttons: [yes, no],
embed: embed 
})
```

Comment: As of the current version (13.1.0), buttons are added with the `components` option, not `buttons`

Comment: Weird, shouldn’t it only be saying "Hello" since the channel.send method now only takes 1 argument, and the embed property doesn’t exist anymore? This indicates they are *probably* on v12 and the `button` options should work if they use the package correctly